# Access Johansen cointegration test results in statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm working with two time series of prices from a same product in distinct markets and I wanted to test if these markets are cointegrated using Johansen cointegration test. However, I only found the statsmodels function that does this test and I did not understand how properly use it.

My dataframe is like this:

```
date    CEASA-PE    CEAGESP
0   2013-08-01  3.790606    1.495000
1   2013-09-01  3.642222    1.417500
2   2013-10-01  3.632727    2.105000
3   2013-11-01  3.868667    3.652941
4   2013-12-01  4.260351    3.862500
... ... ... ...
112 2022-12-01  11.619048   6.782778
113 2023-01-01  11.813636   5.877500
114 2023-02-01  11.900000   6.551667
115 2023-03-01  11.075758   5.080625
116 2023-04-01  9.748333    4.577500
117 rows × 3 columns
```

The code I tried to apply using the function was like:

```
statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.coint_johansen(df,
                                              det_order= 0,
                                              k_ar_diff=0)
```

but it only had returned me:

```
<statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.JohansenTestResult at 0x2ce17d1b4f0>
```

Could someone that have ever used this function help me? Information about how to correctly read the results of this test would be helpfull too.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there!

[As per the documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.coint_johansen.html#statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.coint_johansen-returns), the most important attributes of the results class are:

- `trace_stat` and `trace_stat_crit_vals`
- `max_eig_stat` and `max_eig_stat_crit_vals`

You could see these values as, eg.

```py
out = statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.coint_johansen(df, det_order=0, k_ar_diff=0)

print(out.trace_stat)
print(out.trace_stat_crit_vals)
print(out.max_eig_stat)
print(out.max_eig_stat_crit_vals)
```

You can see a full list of the attributes associated with the `JohansenTestResult` class [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.JohansenTestResult.html#statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.JohansenTestResult).